# How do a change icon when my radio is playing in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a radio station app with flutter, but i need to change the play icon to a pause icon when one of the stations is playing, i'm using some arrays and a list view to show all the stations. Whith this code, it changes de icon, but changes all of them, i just want to change the one tha has been clicked.

here's part of the code

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();  
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  // String url = "http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8193/stream";

  bool isPlaying = false;
  bool isVisible = true;

  @override

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    audioStart();
  }

  Future<void> audioStart() async{
    await FlutterRadio.audioStart();
    print('Audio Start Ok');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final List<String> entries = <String>['Mundo Agro', 'Entre-Ijuis 90.7', 'Horizontina 95.7', 'Caibi 96.7', 'Passos Maia 100.7', 'Palmitos 101.5', 'São Carlos 104.1', 'Irineópolis 105.9'];

    final icons = [Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined];
    
    final iconsP = [Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline];

    // final iconsW = [Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message];
    
    final iconsW = [FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp];

    final urlW = ['', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=555533291263', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=555535373440', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554936480233', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554934351007', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554936470707', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554933254355', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554736251406'];
    
    final lItems = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
    
    final img = ['assets/img/ma.png','assets/img/907.png','assets/img/957.png','assets/img/967.png','assets/img/1007.png','assets/img/1015.png','assets/img/1041.png','assets/img/1059.png'];

    final url = ['http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8193/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8247/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8241/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8187/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8207/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8092/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8141/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8181/stream'];

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Rede Nossa Rádio',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Rede Nossa Rádio'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade400,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ListView.separated(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: entries.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset(
                  img[index],
                  width: 40,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                trailing: Wrap(
                  spacing: -5,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: FaIcon(iconsW[index]),
                      onPressed: () async => await launch(urlW[index]), 
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      // icon: Icon(icons[index]),
                      icon: isPlaying ? Icon(
                          Icons.pause_circle_outline,
                        )
                            : Icon(
                          Icons.play_circle_outline,
                        ),               
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          FlutterRadio.play(url: url[index]);
                          isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                          isVisible = !isVisible;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ), 
                title: Center(
                  child: Text('${entries[index]}'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show all the widget because there is not enough information

Comment: Hello, that is all my widget build code.

Comment: Can you show also your complete statefull widget because I cannot see all the places that you are using the variable isPlaying

Comment: Hello, i 've added the satefull widget as well

Comment: I cannot see the issue. I would recommend to set a breakpoint in the IconButton onPressed method and go step by step to see if your value is changing and if there is a issue because I cannot see a issue in the code. Maybe the issue is in the method you are calling FlutterRadio.play(url: url[index]) try removing it and see if the icon is changing.

Comment: Hello, with this code, the icon changes, but changes for all listtiles on my list view, i need to change on the one that is playing

Comment: Okey I didn't understand your issue. I know what is the problem give me a second and I will give you the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using one value for all your icons and when you update one all will update. You can fix the issue using a index to indicate what sound is playing (-1 means that none are playing) and if you pressed a index that is already playing you will asign -1.

The solution:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();  
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  // String url = "http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8193/stream";

  int isPlaying = -1;
  bool isVisible = true;

  @override

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    audioStart();
  }

  Future<void> audioStart() async{
    await FlutterRadio.audioStart();
    print('Audio Start Ok');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final List<String> entries = <String>['Mundo Agro', 'Entre-Ijuis 90.7', 'Horizontina 95.7', 'Caibi 96.7', 'Passos Maia 100.7', 'Palmitos 101.5', 'São Carlos 104.1', 'Irineópolis 105.9'];

    final icons = [Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined,Icons.play_circle_filled_outlined];
    
    final iconsP = [Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline,Icons.pause_circle_outline];

    // final iconsW = [Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message,Icons.message];
    
    final iconsW = [FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp];

    final urlW = ['', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=555533291263', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=555535373440', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554936480233', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554934351007', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554936470707', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554933254355', 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554736251406'];
    
    final lItems = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
    
    final img = ['assets/img/ma.png','assets/img/907.png','assets/img/957.png','assets/img/967.png','assets/img/1007.png','assets/img/1015.png','assets/img/1041.png','assets/img/1059.png'];

    final url = ['http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8193/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8247/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8241/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8187/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8207/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8092/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8141/stream', 'http://audio8.cmaudioevideo.com:8181/stream'];

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Rede Nossa Rádio',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Rede Nossa Rádio'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade400,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ListView.separated(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: entries.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset(
                  img[index],
                  width: 40,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                trailing: Wrap(
                  spacing: -5,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: FaIcon(iconsW[index]),
                      onPressed: () async => await launch(urlW[index]), 
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      // icon: Icon(icons[index]),
                      icon: isPlaying == index  ? Icon(
                          Icons.pause_circle_outline,
                        )
                            : Icon(
                          Icons.play_circle_outline,
                        ),               
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          FlutterRadio.play(url: url[index]);
                          isPlaying = isPlaying == index ? -1 : index;
                          isVisible = !isVisible;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ), 
                title: Center(
                  child: Text('${entries[index]}'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I would recommend to put your items list in a separate widget and it will be better organized and more easy to read.